# How to get the Github App "vehicle-tracker-api" up and running in Windows

Tags: windows, go, 64-bit

I strived to get up and running the Github repository [vehicle-tracker-api](https://github.com/cad/vehicle-tracker-api) on my box (Windows 8 professional 64 bits) but can't get it right till now...

I followed all the steps as stated in the [readme.md](https://github.com/cad/vehicle-tracker-api/blob/master/README.md) but stumbled.

To fix miscalleanous issues that occured despite sticking properly to the instructions, I managed to install lacking dependencies I identified:

1. Mingw-W64 (explicit)
2. [Swagger 2.0](https://goswagger.io/) (not very sure of it, there might be another better option I doubt but it did the business).

It seems that my troubles lie in the 2 remaining directives in [main.go](https://github.com/cad/vehicle-tracker-api/blob/master/main.go) knowing the first one is fixed so far

```
//go:generate swagger generate spec -o data/swagger.json
//go:generate rm -rf statik/statik.go
//go:generate statik -src data/
package main
```

---

Launching

```
go generate
```

yieds the following error message

```
main.go:2: running "rm": exec: "rm" : executable not found in %PATH%
```

**Question**:

What should I do to get it up and running in Windows?

[Flimzy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13860/flimzy) pointed out in the comment thread below that the build process try to execute the unix-like`rm` command, so

Is there a way to rewrite the platform dependent directive `//go:generate rm -rf statik/statik.go` into the Windows manner.

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem you feel you are facing. I don't see any error messages or claims of actual problems in your description. "Miscellaneous issues" is not specific enough to help.

Comment: @Flimzy There is a step **Build for x86** mentionned in the readme with the instruction $ go build -o vehicle-tracker which mislead me. It doesn't state a Windows support indeed. I'll elaborate.

Comment: That "Build for x86" just means for Intel x86 CPU architecture. "x86" can refer to Windows, Linux, OSX, FreeBSD, and countless others. It is vague, but the final linking step indicates a Linux-like environment was intended.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But please don't include screen shots of text. It's always better to copy-and-paste the text into the question directly.

Comment: @Flimzy My assuption is that there is way to install the missing command as I managed with swagger.exe in C:\Users\USER\go\bin.

Comment: But to answer your question, it appears the program expects a Unix-like environment. It's trying to execute `rm`, which doesn't exist by default on Windows (Windows uses `del` instead). So to get this to work on Windows, you will need to (at least) port all of the Unix-specific bits to work on Windows, too. It may be easy, or it may be incredibly complex.